# javaScript bug in Firefox - Failing to update menu items with active class

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm building one of those "scroll down" websites, with different sections, but basically all you have to/can do is scroll or press the menus which will scroll automatically to the selected section.

I have a piece of js that updates the menu link with the .active class so that when you scroll down, the   respective menu item, for the section you're seeing, will become active.
Altho it works great on Chrome, i can't seem to make it work on Firefox/Explorer.. I just can't find the problem...

I made a small jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/Lxzwfk0u/ ) descriptive of the website i'm building, updating with the active class properly. (at least it shows properly on chrome atm)

Can someone help me find what the problem might be? I've narrowed it down to the little bit of js in the fiddle. I think... (posting here as well, maybe you can spot the error immediately)

```
// add and remove 'active' class by scroll position
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPos = $('body').scrollTop();
        $('nav a').each(function () {
            var currLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top - 40 <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top - 40 + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
                $('nav a').removeClass("active");
                currLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxzwfk0u/2/

The only change I made was here:

```
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
```

When I was echoing this variable before, it would give me a value of 0 in both IE and FireFox. I imagine that this is because there's no scroll bar on the `body` element, but rather it's on the `document` element.

Comment: That worked!! And i've learned something! Thank you!! Unfortunately i don't have enough reputation to upvote you, i'm sorry!!